# Asterisk IVR call to external IVR in other Asterisk machine via IP

Tags: asterisk

It is possible to write a IVR script to call another IVR in other network by ip?

What command should i use?

I am trying this:

```
Goto(from-internal-custom,1235,1@other_asterisk_ip)
```

It is not displaying errors, but not working as expected, because it is communicating to the local from-internal-custom and not with the remote from-internal-custom as i expect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a trunk (can be SIP trunk or IAX trunk) between the two PBX and then you can reach the IVR of the other PBX by passing through the trunk, here a quick example of how-to create a trunk and there is also an example of how-to reach a resource on the remote PBX
http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/connecting_two_asterisk.html